# Dynamic query with single quote

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will create a select statement.

My procedure looks like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE record_example()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE

  unload_query text;
BEGIN
 unload_query := 'query =  ('''select * from my_table''')'; 
 insert into query values (unload_query);
  END;
$$;
```

But its throwing error. Im not able to close the `single quote` properly.

```
LINE 1: SELECT  'query =  ('''select * from my_table''')'
                              ^
QUERY:  SELECT  'query =  ('''select * from my_table''')'
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "record_example" near line 5
```

#### Expected output:

```
Unload query = query = (select * from my table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result of a query inside a string, you need to use the string concatenation operator. Also, subqueries must be surrounded by parentheses.

```
unload_query := 'query =  (''' || (SELECT * FROM my_table) || ''')';
```

This will fail if the query returns more than a single row.

If you want the literal string in `query`, you have too many quotes:

```
unload_query := 'query =  (''select * from my_table'')';
```